# Faster equivalent to worksheetfunction.Clean

Tags: vba, excel, loops

So as part of a larger macro I'm working on, I'm comparing two lists (Omni and MV for short). If a value on the Omni list is also on the MV list, I'd like to copy the row from Omni to a new worksheet. I'm planning on doing this using a nested for loop (outline below), but it only works if I clean out the extra line breaks on  the MV list, which I'm doing using the second set of code below. It takes forever (5 minutes for <50 values), and I was wondering if anybody knew of a faster way to do it.  Thanks!

```
For i = 2 To OmniLastRow Step 1
OmniValue= Workbooks(OmniFileName).Worksheets("pcr").Cells(i, 1)
Workbooks(MVFileName).Worksheets(Yesterday & "_ORPCR_MVTest").Activate
For j = 1 To MVLastRow Step 1
    If Cells(j, 1).Value = OmniValue And Cells(i, 5).Value <> "0" Then
               Workbooks(OmniFileName).Worksheets("pcr").Rows(i).Copy
               MsgBox Cells(j, 1).Value
    End If
Next j

set rng = workbooks(MVFileName).Worksheets(Yesterday & "_PCRMV").activate
For each cell in rng
     cell.value = WorksheetFunction.Clean(cell.value)
Next Cell
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No wonder the code takes time. You are running it on every cell in the sheet.

Limit the range to only the rows and columns with data, for example

```
set rng = workbooks(MVFileName).Worksheets(Yesterday & "_PCRMV").UsedRange
For each cell in rng
     cell.value = WorksheetFunction.Clean(cell.value)
Next Cell
```

Comment: Okay, so this is why you don't try to code while sleep deprived. Fixed the problem, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Further to the answer from @teylyn, block operations are always faster than looping through any range of cells, whether it be the entire worksheet or just the used data range.

```
With Workbooks(MVFileName).Worksheets(Yesterday & "_PCRMV").UsedRange.Cells
    With .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 2)
        '.Replace what:=Chr(9), replacement:=vbNullString, lookat:=xlPart
        '.Replace what:=vbCRLF, replacement:=vbNullString, lookat:=xlPart
        .Replace what:=Chr(10), replacement:=vbNullString, lookat:=xlPart
    End With
End With
```

While that only removes the linefeed characters (e.g. `Chr(10)`) that is what you indicated was the purpose of running the worksheet [CLEAN function](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/clean-function-328724f9-98cc-4a67-a50e-6bd8d33dcc61) against the cell values. Other non-printing characters could also be removed in subsequent Replace operations and still be quicker. Possible candidates would be the <kbd>Tab</kbd> character (e.g. `Chr(9)`) or vbCRLF (e.g. `Chr(13)&Chr(10)`).

I have not used a replacement such as a space as CLEAN simply strips out non-printing characters. You could substitute a space for *vbNullString* if you wish.

Comment: This works on a specifically named worksheet with a filename in the string var MVFileName. How do I do this on the current open XLSX file on currently opened worksheet/tab in Excel 2010?

Comment: I want to store this piece of code in my personal.xlsb file so I can run it on any worksheet I have open. Also, how can I count the number of actual replacements that have been made? I mainly have a problem with unwanted tab characters, but there could be unwated CRLF too.